# Node express server isn't working - how to create and start a server?

Tags: node.js, http, express, server

I am trying to create and start a server and I've been looking at other code and can't see why mine isn't working (just getting this: localhost just keeps loading and loading and nothing happens).
Any ideas? Thanks!!!

app/server/app.js :

```
'use strict'

var express= require ('express');
var path=require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');

var app= express();
module.exports = app;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../browser')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


var server = http.createServer();
  server.listen(1337, function () {
        console.log('Server is listening on port 1337!');
  });

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
console.error(err.stack);
res.status(500).send(err.message);
```

});

app/browser/index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>node</title>   
 </head>
 <body>
    <div>
     <p>Hey whats up</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me.

The only thing wrong in your code is you have to change **server**.listen(1337, function ()..., to **app**.listen(1337, function () {...

Also, I added a file path...

**app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));})**

...to link your localhost:1337 to your index.html file. Now your index.html file will display when you go to localhost:1337.

Lastly, I'm not sure if you need this line... **var server = http.createServer();**. I deleted it and everything worked fine.

Here's the code below.

```js
'use strict'

var express= require ('express');
var path=require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');

var app= express();
module.exports = app;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../browser')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
})

  app.listen(1337, function () {
        console.log('Server is listening on port 1337!');
  });

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
console.error(err.stack);
res.status(500).send(err.message);

});
```

Comment: Thank you it works now. It all started working when I changed it to app.listen as you said. Could you explain to me why var server = http.createServer(); and server.listen does not work so I understand it? As Ive seen in tutorials, I first have to create a server -doing it through: var server = http.createServer(); and then I start my server - thats why server.listen (so I start the server I have previously created. Why is that wrong and how does - app.listen - work (if I don't create a server, how can I start it through app.listen?). thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure. So I'm not sure if this is 100% correct, but I believe Express has it's own HTTP module. I believe if you were **NOT** using Express, **THEN** you would use **var server = http.createServer();**, and **server.listen**, the way you had it before. But since you **ARE** using Express, which makes things easier with routing and other features, then you can use Express to create the server. This is what you are doing with the code **app.listen**. Because **var app = express()**, and **app.listen** is the same as saying **express().listen**, this means you are creating the server using Expres

Comment: thank you. so app.list both creates the server and starts it or var app=express() automatically creates a server and then i start it using app.listen?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the port You wrote - 1337 is busy, check by choosing other port, for example 4200, or 3000 - `server.listen(4200,function () {`